# Python Selenium - all options from flexible list

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am new to python and searched this forum for a day now but could not find an answer to my question.

I am trying to retrieve all elements from a flexible dropdown list (elements only show when courser is over them), save them in a list, and use the list to click every element from it to open the website underlying.

This is my website: http://avi2.osamsterdam.nl/index.mpl

I can select the elements of the first dropdown list and click to open the second selection box, but then I am stuck, since these have no class (class = ""). Any idea how I can "grab" them?

I already tried select., but the items cannot be selected...

My code:

```
navigate_to_website(driver, website) # open website with driver 
# open fist dropdown list:
area = driver.find_element_by_id("geo") 
area.click() 
# find the first choice:
select = [x for x in area.find_elements_by_class_name("expandable")] 
for element in select:
    print (element.text) #options to choose from
    if element.text == "Buurt": #option desired
        element.click()
        break
# it does not work as of here: 
buurt = [x for x in element.find_element_by_link_text('javascript:void')]
for buurten in buurt:
  print (buurten.text)
```

If you need more information, please let me know.

Here an example of the dropdown list:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndp94.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `buurt = [x for x in element.find_element_by_link_text('javascript:void')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code helps you:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url="http://avi2.osamsterdam.nl/index.mpl"

locatorOne='//a[@class="expandable" and contains(text(),"Amsterdam")]'
locatorTwo='//a[@class="expandable" and contains(text(),"Stadsdeel")]'
locatorThree='//a[@class="expandable" and contains(text(),"Buurt")]'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)

area = driver.find_element_by_id("geo")
area.click()

#to select the option
option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, locatorThree)))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(option).perform()


thirdOption = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="geo"]/li/ul/li[3]')
ele=thirdOption.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for e in ele:
    print e.text
```

It will print all element text of Buurt as:

```
Burgwallen-Oude Zijde
Burgwallen-Nieuwe Zijde
Grachtengordel-West
Grachtengordel-Zuid
Nieuwmarkt/Lastage
Haarlemmerbuurt
Jordaan
De Weteringschans
Weesperbuurt/Plantage
Oostelijke Eilanden/Kadijken
Spaarnd.- en Zeeheldenbuurt
Staatsliedenbuurt
Centrale Markt/Fred. Hendrikbrt
Da Costabuurt
Kinkerbuurt
Van Lennepbuurt
Helmersbuurt
Overtoomse Sluis
Indische Buurt West
Indische Buurt Oost
Oostelijk Havengebied
IJburg West
Landlust
Erasmuspark
De Kolenkit
Geuzenbuurt
Chassébuurt
Van Galenbuurt
Hoofdweg e.o.
Westindische Buurt
Volewijck
IJplein/Vogelbuurt
Tuindorp Nieuwendam/- Buiksloot
Tuindorp Oostzaan
Oostzanerwerf/Kadoelen
Nieuwendam-Noord
Buikslotermeer
Banne Buiksloot
Waterland/Ndamham/dijken
Slotermeer-Noordoost
Slotermeer-Zuidwest
Geuzenveld
Eendracht
Lutkemeer/Ookmeer
Osdorp-Oost
Osdorp-Midden
De Punt
MAP/Sloten/Lutke-/Ookmeer
Slotervaart
Overtoomse Veld
Westlandgracht
Sloter-/Riekerpolder
Bijlmer Centrum (D,F,H)
Bijlmer Oost (E,G,K)
Nellestein
Holendrecht/Reigersbos
Gein
Driemond
Weesperzijde
Oosterparkbuurt
Dapperbuurt
Transvaalbuurt
Frankendael
Middenmeer
Betondorp/De Omval
Oude Pijp
Nieuwe Pijp
Diamantbuurt
Hoofddorppleinbuurt
Schinkelbuurt
Willemspark
Museumkwartier/Duivelseiland
Stadionbuurt
Apollobuurt
Scheldebuurt
IJselbuurt
Rijnbuurt
Buitenveldert-West/Zuid/WTC
Buitenveldert-Oost
```

Comment: thank you! it does what it should and I guess I can go on from here.

Comment: may I ask how you got the strings for the variables "locatorOne, two, three"? I normally copy the Xpath from the developer viewer in chrome, but it is way shorter. Maybe that could help me in the future.

Comment: you have to learn to write custom xpaths: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html and http://learn-automation.com/how-to-write-dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/ will help